# Unable to use MATERIAL-UI & React through unpkg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, babeljs

I am trying to load react and material ui directly through a cdn but am unable to get material ui to work.

Here is the code I have tried so far

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Bundleless React</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.production.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./index.jsx" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

index.jsx

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

The above code works fine with just React but when I try using a material UI component like below it throws an error.

index.jsx

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
    Hello World
  </Button>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The above code throws a `Button is not defined` error in the console. How exactly do I solve this?